# Authentication token manipulation error

Tags: password-recovery

I forgot my Ubuntu password so I booted into recovery and dropped into a root shell prompt and this is what happened:

```
root@username-PC:~# passwd username
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Comment: Another possible solution can be found at [root can change the password of a user, but the user herself cannot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1058610/250300).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Also make sure you are mounting the file system read/write.

After immediately selecting 'Drop into root shell prompt' I found the filesystem was mounted read only, which prevents resetting the password.

Choosing the option to remount `/` as `read/write` and going back into the root shell prompt enabled the password change.

The command to run prior to changing the password is: `mount -rw -o remount /`

Comment: even after following these steps it will not accept my password

Comment: Odd. `mount` showed that `/` was already mounted as read/write, but `mount -rw -o remount /` still worked. No idea why.

Comment: i am simply one of those idiots who did not read the stdout and forgot to put in the "(current) Unix password" but the password that I want it to be :(

Comment: +1 - Obvious but not assumed. TY! Also, Ubuntu would be smart to mention this when dropping into root shell when using 'recovery' option.. along with a warning about root rw usage..

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure how it happened. A sudo user created my account then deleted it then created it again.

Here is what I found

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

No change.

```
sudo pwck
```

Showed no errors.

```
sudo grpck
```

Showed no errors.

```
ls -l /etc/passwd /etc/group /etc/shadow /etc/shadow-
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    767 May  7 16:45 /etc/group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1380 May  7 16:45 /etc/passwd
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1025 May  8 09:11 /etc/shadow
-rw------- 1 root root   1025 May  7 16:46 /etc/shadow-
```

Looks normal.

```
sudo cat /etc/shadow |grep oracle
oracle:$6$FsPqyplr$DrIvjFDSx0ipHmECMw1AU5hTrbNMnnkGRdFlaQcM.p3Rdu2OLjY20tzUTW61HlFH16cal56rKlLuW4j2mK9D.:15833:0:99999:7:::
```

Showed user and encrypted password.

```
sudo cat /etc/shadow- |grep oracle
```

Showed nothing. Not sure what that means but doesn't look right.

```
sudo passwd -d oracle
passwd
```

So the solution was to delete the password then reset new password.

Hope this helps.

I originally posted here [Getting an "Authentication token manipulation" error when trying to change my user password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us) but google shows this result first so, I re-posted.

Comment: Use pam-auth-update to ensure that Kerberos is not used as one of pam authentication options - if so, passwd leads to Authentication token manipulation error

Comment: Funny: my problem was that "a sudo user created my account then deleted it" unbeknownst to me. As a sudo user myself, I "then created it again". Your last piece of code worked for me (Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 5):

I got this error by changing password with device where date was not set. (ie. it was random after boot)

Basically what happened was that when I changed the password the illegal timestamp got updated to `/etc/shadow`. After that one could not use that account to login or change its password. Even with root account it was impossible to change that password again.

To fix the account I had to:

1. Set the correct date
2. Edit sane expiration/last password change dates to `/etc/shadow` file (I used last working shadow file)
3. Change the password with root-rights to new one.

Answer (score 5):

This error is coming from PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module) which says the module was unable to obtain the new authentication token (check `auth.log` for more details about this error).

This is related to your authorization settings found in `/etc/pam.d/` directory (such as [`minimum_uid` in `common-auth`](https://serverfault.com/q/506927/130437) or some other restrictions **requisite** marks). So please double check that the settings in PAM module are correct.

See: [`man pam_chauthtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_chauthtok)

> `PAM_AUTHTOK_ERR`: A module was unable to obtain the new authentication token.

---

Sometimes this error may happen when changing password for a user which didn't have the current password set yet and `passwd` still asks for it, so the workaround is to force the change by adding `sudo`, e.g.: `sudo passwd $USER`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have LikeWise or PowerBroker installed, this will occur for `root`.  I was forced to uninstall pbis-open (which i was not using anymore).

```
sudo aptitude purge pbis-open pbis-open-legacy pbis-open-gui pbis-open-upgrade
```