# I want to change my administrator password but am receiving an error"manipulation token authentication error"

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Authentication token manipulation error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error)

I want to change my ubuntu 11.10 administrator account password but when i am about to do so, i get an error that "passwd:Manipulation Token Authentication Error" and then in the next statement get"passwd:password unchanged"...So can anyone help me out by finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Ubuntu, the filesystem is mounted as read-only, so you need to enter the follow command to get it to remount as read-write, which will allow you to make changes :

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Not doing this will cause that error.