# password help please

Tags: login, password-recovery

I have version 11.10 and am having trouble login in can only access guest account and cannot get into adminastrator account. I have gone to root menu and tried to enter password change it posts authentication token manipulation error  password unchanged. What can i do to get back adminastration account?

Comment: In the worst case, you can boot an Ubuntu liveCD, open a terminal window, become root, and mount the hard drive on the troubled system.  From there you could save important files, edit the /etc/sudoers to make it easier to get root, or take other steps...

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here. Remount root with read/write privileges.

[Authentication token manipulation error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error)

Answer (score 0):

Go to console by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and login as yourself, you will be your home directory. Then simply delete the `.Xauthority` and reboot using the following command:

```
sudo rm .Xauthority`
sudo shutdown -r now`
```

Then you should be able to login under your profile.