# I cant login in Ubuntu Server after passwd command

Tags: login, password, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Authentication token manipulation error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error)

I installed **Ubuntu Server** using **Oracle VM** on my Windows 7 for practicing GNU commands.

I used the `passwd` tool but **after using the command I am not able to login** into my Ubuntu.

When I type my password nothing happens. Nothing gets written on the black screen. And when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it says `_login incorrect_` And one more thing is says `_hint: num lock on_`

When I tried to change the password into recovery mode it says:

```
_Authentication token manipulation error_
```

I reinstalled my virtual machine but the problem persist.

Comment: So, is your [Num Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num_lock) on?

Answer (score 0):

The password not showing is normal on a non-graphical login.

You can test that the keyboard types what you think it types by typing your password in as the login name.

Try [searching for Authentication token manipulation error](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Authentication%20token%20manipulation%20error)...