# remounting as read/write -- will I lose my data?

Tags: mount, backup, read-only

I need root access to install a file, but I seem to have forgotten my pw. To change it, it appears I will need to enter GRUB and remount `/` as read/write as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error).

I just want to know if I will need to back up my computer before doing this.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need to. But of course you should make backups from time to time.