# How to add user to Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Normally I would just do:

```
sudo adduser anewuser
```

and then provide the initial password.

However in Ubuntu Phone I get:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Error `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error` occurs generally in following scenario:

- File system mounted as read-only.
- Incorrect Permissions on system files.

In your case, as you're working with [Ubuntu Touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch), I'm guessing that your system is mounted in **Read-Only** mode, as this is general security feature of any Mobile Phone OS to reduce risk of overwriting System Files by any other services/application accidentally or purposefully.

Solution could be remount file-system in Read/Write mode, and also by checking File-permissions & Correct it if required to make sure you're changes will make through!

- [Remount File-System](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error/)
- [Check File-permissions and Remount File-System](https://www.tecmint.com/fix-passwd-authentication-token-manipulation-error-in-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Touch currently is not designed for a multi-user use case.

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation or something that documents this?