# Cannot bypass the password?

Tags: passwd

I forgot my Ubuntu password. I followed the steps given on your sites and I almost reached the end, but then my computer said:

```
passwd: authentication token manipulation error
```

I tried to do it again many times but it comes to the same result. I cannot open my account.

Comment: Please give a full list of the steps you performed and the complete command that produced this output. Partial snippets are not too helpful.

Comment: This happens because the filesystem that contains the password database is mounted readonly. Procedures for resetting the password usually contain a step to remount it readwrite first, before running `passwd`. See [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) and [Authentication token manipulation error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Authentication Token Manipulation Error when trying to update user's password in Ubuntu because your root filesystem was mounted as read only, which prevents changing the password.

To mount it read/write, enter the command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```