# root can change the password of a user, but the user herself cannot

Tags: 16.04, password

I want to change the password of a user in Ubuntu.

- I am able to do this as root (administrator).

  ```
  root@xxx:~# passwd testuser
  Enter new UNIX password:
  Retype new UNIX password:
  passwd: password updated successfully
  ```
- While occurred the following error if doing this in the user's own account.

  ```
  testuser@xxx:~$ passwd
  Changing password for testuser.
  (current) UNIX password:
  Enter new UNIX password:
  Retype new UNIX password:
  passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
  passwd: password unchanged
  ```

Other system info:

- My `/` is mounted as read/write.
- And here are my permission settings:

  ```
  root@xxx:~# ls -al /etc/shadow /etc/passwd
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3083 Jul 23 15:17 /etc/passwd
  -rw-r----- 1 root shadow 3176 Jul 23 16:26 /etc/shadow

  root@xxx:~# ls -al $(which passwd)
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 54256 May 17 2017 /usr/bin/passwd
  ```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: @PerlDuck  `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 54256 May 17  2017 /usr/bin/passwd`

Comment: Note to CVers: I meanwhile think ***this is not a duplicate*** because the missing SETUID bit is a completely different thing. Only the symptoms are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `/usr/bin/passwd` needs the *setuid* bit in 
its permissions to operate properly for non-root users.

From the comments we learned that the permissions of your command currently are

```
ls -al $(which passwd)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 54256 May 17 2017 /usr/bin/passwd
```

To add the `s` bit do:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/passwd
# or sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/passwd
```

so it becomes:

```
ls -al $(which passwd)
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 54256 May 17 2017 /usr/bin/passwd
```

Note the `s` instead of the first `x`.

Also note that by default the `s` bit is set, so someone must have removed it. Maybe deliberatley, to prevent users from changing their passwords. Maybe by accident, because the combination of *`chmod`, recursion, the root directory, and seven-five-five* is so much fun. (Don't do that, because it may render your system useless!)