# How to login into Ubuntu after an upgrade to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, login, password

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. The upgrade went smoothly. I did a restart and then strange things started to happen.

After each upgrade I set my Ubuntu to automatic login(been upgrading from 10.04 until now without a fresh installation, always 64-bit). As expected yesterday the login window appeared. The first thing that caught my eye were the lines below my user name. They say "No value has been set". Then I type in my password as usual. And then the big one: "Invalid password, please try again"!

From that time on I tried a couple of things:

1. Tried my different passwords. I always use the same password for Ubuntu but still I gave it a shot.
2. My default language in Ubuntu is English. That is different from my keyboard layout that has a Slovenian layout. It has been a problem before that our Slovenian layout keyboard and English OS don't always cooperate as they should. That is the reason my Ubuntu password has only numbers and English letters. So I tried the on screen keyboard in Ubuntu to click my way through the login again no success.
3. Then I tried to change my password. I followed these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html). First through GRUB. After typing in "passwd *myusername*" I got a puzzling response. The terminal said:

   ```
   passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
   passwd: password unchanged
   ```

   The file system state was read/write because I used `fsck` command before going into root. Then I tried the second option with the Live CD. Erased the password from the *shadow* file but still no success logging in Ubuntu.

Then there is the thing with the Guest session account. No matter which option I choose (Ubuntu, Ubuntu 2D.) and login nothing happens. The screen goes blank for 3 seconds, the hard disk makes some noise and the login screen comes back on.

Now I don't know what to do next. I have a dual-boot system and Win7 boots up without problems. Ubuntu 11.04 runs great from Live CD. I did a `memtest` just to be sure and there were no errors. So I am kind of certain it is not a hardware problem.

Link to the contents of [lightdm.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/950723/).

If you require any further information or if I was unclear please let me know!
What else can I do?

Comment: can you change to a virtual console and have a look at the lightdm log ? `sudo less /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`

Comment: Virtual console that is accessible by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1? That worked just one time and I couldn't login there either. If I do that now the screen goes blank and monitor shuts down completly. If use CTRL+ALT+F7 the login screen comes back up. Now I went and checked /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log with a LiveCD. I am not sure what to watch for. Can I post the .log somewhere or send it to you?

Comment: Please use [ubuntu paste bin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and edit your post and add the link to it.

Comment: Link to the lightdm.log added.

Comment: Can you try booting into console mode and see if your password works then ? Please see [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Editing_the_GRUB_2_Menu_During_Boot) how to boot into console mode. Add `text` in the "linux /boot/vmlinuz..."  after "quiet splash"

Comment: The same happened in the console. It says _Login incorrect_. I tried with the original _shadow_ file and the one with the password deleted. One more question though-is it normal to have two shadow files? I have two; one is named _shadow_ and the other _shadow-_.

Comment: the second one is a backup. Have you tried [this ?](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

Comment: Yes I tried that. That is when I got the `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error`.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error) and [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us) ?

Comment: I am sure that i had read/write privileges because I could run `ls /home`. I checked the date in Bios and it is correct. I checked the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` and my user name is in both files. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. After upgrading to 12.04, I could not login anymore, neither from the GUI nor from the console. After booting in recoverymode ([see here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)) and mounting / read-write, changing the password via `passwd`*username*  seemed to work, but I still could not login afterwards.

The problem was in /etc/passwd. My shell was set to /usr/bin/tcsh, which does no longer work. It must be /bin/sh. (I personally find it sad that Ubuntu forces me now to use this shell, but I can workaround it).

By the way, I found it because I deleted the user via `userdel`*username* and recreated the user `useradd`*username*, and afterwards it worked. I had to fix the user and group number in passwd manually afterwards, that is the exact steps were:

- move home directory to somewhere else (to avoid that userdel would remove it)
- look into /etc/passwd and write down the group and user number (normally 1000)
- userdel myusername
- useradd myusername
- passwd myusername
- edit /etc/passwd to ensure that the group and user number is still the same
- move home directory back to its original plase
- login myusername => to test that it works now

Then I saw that the shell changed and I tried to change the shell (`useradd -s /usr/bin/tcsh myusername`) and then nothing worked again. So, stick with /bin/sh.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your solution. I haven't tried it though because I did a quick reinstall and everything worked afterwards. Thank you anyway!