# Why I can't change my password in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, password

I tried multiple times in terminal to change my password. but it throwing error but i filled up all requirements.

```
naga@naga:~$ passwd 

Current password: 
New password: 

Re-enter password: 

Password does not meet requirements
passwd: 

Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: 

password unchanged

naga@naga:~$
```

Comment: Is it because your password is too simple? Just a thought :)

Comment: i used numeric,alphapets and special characters too in my password and it's length is 12 is it simple?

Comment: Maybe it checks small passages in the password and it contains your user name or simple passages that are forbidden. Does it work with other passwords?

Comment: @chocobai i checked everything but it's not working :(

Comment: I think the setuid bit has to be set on passwd or something, maybe this went somehow wrong? This is how my ls-lh looks like on passwd:
    -rwsr-xr-x 1 root   root      46K Apr 18 03:28 passwd
About setuid bit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid
I think the fourth character should be the setuid bit... or something :D

Comment: Is this a regular Ubuntu installation with local authentication? Or are you connected to an Active Directory/LDAP or something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an "Authentication token manipulation" error when trying to change my user password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us)

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you filesystem is mounted with read-write permissions(are you in Recovery mode?).

To mount your filesystem in read-write mode, in the terminal type:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
```

and then change your password using `passwd <username>`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

Going to `System Settings>User Account`

- Under `Login Options`:
- Clicking where it shows bullets next to `password`
- Follow the directions in the new window

Comment: I tried that too but I can change my new password from the generated password but I can't change it to what I want. @AnythinkM3tal