# administrative passwd how to change it in the root

Tags: passwd

each time i go to the root and try to change my passwd an error occurs and it says authencation manipulation error or some thing like that.and btw the passwd s match.
whoever knows whats happening please help.HOw DO I CHANGE MY PASSWD .

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT AT US. WE TRY TO HELP HERE!

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message you're getting - how are we supposed to work with 'or something like that'???

Comment: @cjc See [Getting an “Authentication token manipulation” error when trying to change my user password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us). Assuming this is happening while attempting to reset a password from recovery mode, I suspect the problem is that you need to [remount your filesystem readwrite as explained in Luis Alvarado's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/117433/22949).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to root to change your password. Simply type the following in your terminal

```
passwd
```

Done!