# Authentication error , please try again later

Tags: data-recovery

After login to ubuntu, whenever I try to change any settings it gives authentication attempt failed error.. But when I tried to change the password using recovery mode it gave authentication token manipulation error..?? Can anybody help me with this issue??

Comment: You can refer the url for authentication error : http://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us

Answer (score 0):

First Enable super user account password on Ubuntu

set a password for root user as shown below.

```
$ sudo passwd root
[sudo] password for ramesh:
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Now with the new password you can login as super user with su command

```
$ su -
Password:
#
```

now you try that what ever you want its access it. but if this also not working must comment me ....:)