# Resetting my password through the root doesn't work

Tags: password

I went to the root, and then typed in "passwd username" except I used my username. Instead of giving me an option to change the password, it says "Usage: passwd [options] [LOGIN]" and then gives me all of these options that dont even work when I try them.

Comment: How did you "go to the root"?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to go into root if you're already logged in.

Simply run the command, with no arguments:

```
passwd
```

```
tim@Hairy14:~$ passwd
Changing password for tim.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
password changed
```

Comment: I did that, and it wont let me type anything. It says authenitcation token manipulation error

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us