# How to check security on Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, login, password, security

Today while I was trying to install a new software via software center, my password stopped working, that was strange for me after that situation I tried searching askubuntu.com to reset my user password and came to the solution given here:

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

and that worked fine, I changed my password successfully. But after that another situation occurred, the password for user root was not working too. I was shocked because yesterday my password for user root and login user both were working fine, so I assumed that my system was hacked. 
When I tried to change password for root using the above solution, I ended up with "Authentication token manipulation error",
I searched again and  thanks to AskUbuntu community, I got solution for that too here:

[Getting an "Authentication token manipulation" error when trying to change my user password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us)
by using command

```
 sudo passwd root
```

Now I need help to secure my Ubuntu Machine. Is there any GUI Application to check the vulnerabilities in my Machine, which can suggest steps to secure it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that "GUI" and "Security" belong in the same question. Are you really looking for "Click here to be insecure/secure"?

A command-line tool that I currently use is `lynis` dowloadable from https://cisofy.com/lynis/ Does not fix things, just points out things that should be fixed.

However, since you didn't figure out what was going on back when "Today while I was trying to install a new software via software center, my password stopped working", you're probably doomed to remain confused. Stop changing your system until you figure out how you got to the current state. Any "fix" applied without this understanding will probably make things worse.

Comment: my both passwords (user and root)weren't working and after following the steps mentioned in those answers and resetting them my new passwords now work fine.