# Why does 'passwd' fail to change user's pw

Tags: login, passwd

** Term-control chars edited out:

```
Script started on 2017-12-01 06:51:43-0500
/etc/bash.bashrc
~root/.bashrc
declare -x PATH="/root/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/root/bin:/root/.emacs.d/term-cmd:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/snap/bin:/root/Scripts"
declare -x HOME="/root"

bash # passwd bunky

Current Kerberos password: 

New password: 

Retype new password: 

Current Kerberos password: 

Current password: 

passwd: Authentication token manipulation error

passwd: password unchanged


bash exit
#################################
```

1) I have never set up Kerberos.  Why is passwd asking for "Current Kerberos password?

2) As root, I should not require to know 's "current password".

3) In fact, an unknown problem with the user's old password is the reason for the whole exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several of the suggestions in [Getting an "Authentication token manipulation" error when trying to change my user password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us) until something worked.

I *think* the successful one was 'pam-auth-update'