# Ubuntu 16.04, pbis, authentication token manipulation problem

Tags: password, password-recovery, passwd

I have a huge problem with my Ubuntu since I tried to change the password. 
My Desktop is connected with a windows domain using pbis-open. From time to time I have to change my domain password and normally use the same password for my Ubuntu then.

This time, after changing domain password (while connected with domain from Ubuntu) I ran into the error "Authentication token manipulation error".

I searched the internet finding different proposals like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error?newreg=717a2fbbe01447f99e80239dd73055f6) or [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us).

All I tried just made things worse.

The only thing I can still do is login. In gnome, lock screen returns this error and sudo is not working anymore. Sudo is not returning any error here, just don't accept the password.

In simple console I am at least able to use sudo but passwd also returns the autenthication token error before even entering the password.

what I can see in auth log:

```
passwd[11821]: [lsass-pam] [module:pam_lsass]LsaPamCheckCurrentPassword failed [login:foo][error code: 40008]
```

(Found nothing regarding error 40008.)

pwconv had no effect. pwck grpck show no errors.
/etc/shadow don't show encrypted password:

```
foo::17550:0:99999:7:::


sudo passwd -d foo
```

returns error

```
passwd: password expiry information changed.
```

pam-auth-update didn't help anything in different combinations.

I am running out of ideas here and any help to fix this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of headache, research, reading, trial and error finally I have a solution for this problem. 
Reading through the PBIS guides I found command

```
domainjoin-cli leave <user>
```

At the end it was that simple (like always when knowing). After I left the domain this way everything worked again as expected and I was able to use and change all my accounts and passwords. 
I restarted, joined the domain again and everything works like a charm.
Unfortunately I don't know what exactly happens there, restarting the whole machine did not change anything, I had to leave explicitly. 
I can only guess that some cache data was deleted that caused this weird problem.

I hope this can help anyone preventing time waste and headache.