# Why sudo passwd username keeps asking for the current password

Tags: 16.04, passwd

I am in a bizarre situation, that I can't reset user's password on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04) using eighter `sudo passwd username` or `passwd username` from the root account.

```
root@adam-minipc:~ # passwd mikolaj
Current password: 
New password: 
New password (again): 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

In the `/etc/shadow` the relevant entry reads:

```
mikolaj:!:18063:0:99999:7:::
```

Why is that? What cause it and how to reset the password already? Have I been pwned?

---

Unlocking the account does not help either:

```
root@adam-minipc:~ # passwd -u mikolaj
passwd: unlocking the password would result in a passwordless account.
You should set a password with usermod -p to unlock the password of this account.
```

`usermod -p <encrypted password> mikolaj` requires encrypted password, and it simply pastes it to the `/etc/shadow` file. I don't know how to get the encrypted password, even if I knew, it must be a way to simply reset a password if you are root. It is the first time I see this behavior of `passwd` and frankly I am really at lost.

---

The question is different from [Getting an "Authentication token manipulation" error when trying to change my user password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620), because it has nothing to do with the read-only file system, nor I complain about the error in the first place. I want to know, why `sudo passwd <username>` suddenly started asking for a current password. On all my other systems it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried setting a password with "-p" as the output suggests?

Comment: @KetanPatel No, it is not. I've just found the solution and it is a completely different story.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski [That](https://askubuntu.com/q/57620) covers multiple causes, though none mentions `passwd` asking root to give a current password. I think [jouell's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/632673) *might've* fixed this. I recommend you [edit] again to make immediately clear what you're *currently* asking for. (It still *looks* like you want to reset the password.) Does `passwd mikolaj`, as root, still ask for `mikolaj`'s password? If not, it may be hard to find why it did. If so, does `pam-auth-update` fix it? If not, what's the output of `ls -l /etc/{passwd,group} /etc/pam.d/*pass*`?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -u username passwd`?

Answer (score 6):

I've finally found the solution, but it does not answer why `sudo passwd <username>` suddenly started asking for the current password, so I am not going to mark it as a solution.

To solve it run as root `usermod -p "" mikolaj`, and then change the password using `passwd` as always, and when it asks you for the current password, simply press enter without typing anything.

Comment: Removing the exclamation mark from /etc/shadow would have been the same I guess. Nice solution. :-)

Comment: Hmm... I'm skeptical that this really solved the underlying issue, since to *actually* set the password to the empty string you would need something like `usermod -p "$(openssl passwd "")"`. Is `passwd mikolaj` as root behaving normally again now?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, it does. All is fine now, except for my lack of understanding why `passwd` started to behave like this